# 'webcolors' has no attribute 'css3_hex_to_names'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using this Function

```
def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]
```

I am using Webcolor 1.11.1 Python 3.8.8 and I am getting this Error in line

```
for key, name in webcolors.css21_hex_to_names.items():
```

**AttributeError**: module 'webcolors' has no attribute 'css21_hex_to_names'

Answer (score 9):

Luckily, I found the solution to this.
Instead of **webcolors.css21_hex_to_names** I used this **webcolors.CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES**.
CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES in Capitals